# How to get Google Calendar JSON feed working with Phonegap?

Tags: android, json, cordova, jquery-mobile, google-calendar-api

I am making an app using Phonegap.  In this app I want to get a list of events from a public calendar and display them.

It works fine when testing in a browser but I get an error when using a device.

```
$.ajax({
      url: url+'&timeMin='+today+'&key='+key,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) 
      { 
          //etc
```

Error Message:

```
{
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
     "domain": "usageLimits",
      "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
       "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
       "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
    "code": 403,
     "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
 }
}
```

I have tried using both a browser key and android key from Google Developer's console neither one works.  I have not really tried to get it working using OAUTH because that seems to be overkill for what I am trying to accomplish.  And like I said, it works fine when testing in a browser.

I use Phonegap Build to build the apk so I don't know if there is anything going on there that is hidden from me that could be causing this.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Did you enable calendar API in developers console?? Also, Try setting the "Referers" to "Any referer allowed" for your project (just leave the field empty) if it is not already like that.

To do this go to your console and open Api & auth/ Credentials and click "Edit allowed referers" empty the input field.

Comment: That actually worked.  I had a * in the Referrers field thinking that was to allow all.  Removing it and leaving the field blank fixed the issue.  If you resubmit this as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable calendar API in developers console?? Also, Try setting the "Referers" to "Any referer allowed" for your project (just leave the field empty) if it is not already like that. To do this go to your console and open Api & auth/ Credentials and click "Edit allowed referers" empty the input field.

Answer (score 0):

@SGC I tried this but you NEED a referrer site address to use the HTTP Referrers option. If you try to leave it blank you won't be able to save that setting. It tells you to select NONE which means that API key is vulnerable I think. Is this true?

[image: Screenshot]

If I select NONE I can see the calendar events from my website on my android phone, but if I restrict the API to *.mywebsite.com/* then for some reason my android phone (viewing site in chrome) doesn't load the cal events. Is NONE a really bad idea?
Thanks